# Lower bounding $|1+z+\cdots + z^{n-1}|$ when $z\approx 1$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I am trying to lower bound $|1+z+\cdots + z^{n-1}|$ when $z$ is a complex number close to $1$ (and $n$ is sufficiently large).  My main concern occurs in the case $z = 1 + it$, where $t$ is small.  In these cases, the terms of the geometric series spiral around the origin, but because $|z| > 1$ these terms do not fully cancel with each other.  Naive applications of the Triangle Inequality fail to capture the oscillation of the powers of $z$ around the origin and I'm having trouble accounting for that.

For example, it is tempting to write
$$|1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1}| = \frac{|z^n - 1|}{|z - 1|} \geq \frac{|z|^n - 1}{|z - 1|},$$
but this is too weak when $z$ is small, as the below graph shows
(orange: $t^{-1}|(1+it)^n - 1|$; blue: $t^{-1}(|1+it|^n-1)$, as a function of $t$ for $n=80$)

[image]
Are there any known bounds or techniques for dealing with lower bounds for sums of this form?  I'm surprised I have not been able to find any yet, though perhaps I am not searching in the right places.

Comment: I know it's obvious but a good edit would be to add a caption or a description of the figure (who's orange and who's blue). Wonderful q...

Comment: @AmirSagiv --- good point, I added the description

Answer (score 34):

How about $t^{-1}|e^{int}-1|=t^{-1}\sqrt{2-2\cos nt}$? Here is the comparison plot for $n=80$.

[image]

Orange: $|1+z+z^2\cdots +z^{n-1}|$ with $z=1+it$ and $n=80$, as a function of $t$;
Blue $t^{-1}|e^{int}-1|$ for $n=80$.

To check that the orange curve indeed lies above the blue curve for small $t$, note that
$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}t^{-4}\bigl(|(1+it)^n-1|^2-|e^{int}-1|^2\bigr)=(6n-5)n^2/12>0$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Wow, that is surprisingly strong for small $t$.  It might be possible to combine this with techniques I've previously used to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DavidAltizio, if you like the answer of Carlo (as I do) consider to accept it. Carlo, I'm curious about how did you find such a beautiful and elementary asymptotics: could you give me some insight?

Comment: This is motivated by the large-$n$ limit $(1+x/n)^n\rightarrow e^x$

Comment: Is is an heuristic or did you establish rigorously this upper bound?

Comment: I checked the bound for $t\ll 1$, where the two curves approach each other.

Answer (score 22):

Just a note that Carlo's nice inequality
$$ \left|\left(1+\frac{it}{n}\right)^n - 1\right| \geq |e^{it} - 1| \label{1}\tag{1}$$
in fact is valid for all real $t$ and natural numbers $n \geq 1$.  For $n=1,2$ this is clear since $e^{it}$ is $1$-Lipschitz and
$$\left|\left(1+\frac{it}{2}\right)^2 - 1\right| = \sqrt{t^2 + (t^2/4)^2} \geq |t| = |(1+it)-1|,$$ so suppose that $n \geq 3$. [Note that this calculation shows that the left-hand side of (1) is not always decreasing in $n$, despite converging to the right-hand side in the limit $n \to \infty$.]

Without loss of generality we may take $t$ to be positive. In the limit $n \to \infty$, $\big(1+\frac{it}{n}\big)^n$ converges to $e^{it}$.  To try to take advantage of this approximation, we can write $\big(1+\frac{it}{n}\big)^n$ in polar coordinates as $re^{i(t-\varepsilon)}$, where
$$ r := \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}$$
and
$$ \varepsilon := t - n \mathrm{arctan} \frac{t}{n}.$$
We would like to use the Taylor approximation $\mathrm{arctan} x \approx x - x^3/3$ for all $x$ (not necessarily close to zero).  Indeed, on integrating the inequalities $1-x^2 \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq 1$ we have $x-\frac{x^3}{3} \leq \mathrm{arctan} x \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$, thus
$$ 0 \leq \varepsilon \leq \frac{t^3}{3n^2} \label{2}\tag{2}.$$
The inequality \eqref{1} squares to
$$ r^2 + 1 - 2r \cos(t-\varepsilon) \geq 2 - 2 \cos t.$$
We can rearrange this as
$$ (r-1)^2 + 2(r-1) (1 - \cos(t-\varepsilon)) \geq 2 (\cos(t-\varepsilon)-\cos(t)).\label{3} \tag{3}$$
When $t$ is large, $r-1$ is very large, and so we expect the first term on the left-hand side to dominate.  Since
$$ r-1 = \left(1 + \frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2} - 1 \geq \frac{n}{2} \frac{t^2}{n^2} \label{4}\tag{4}$$
and
$$ \cos(t-\varepsilon) - \cos(t) \leq \varepsilon \leq \frac{t^3}{3n^2} \label{5}\tag{5}$$
this inequality \eqref{3} is already satisfied (just using the first term on the LHS) if
$$ \left(\frac{n}{2} \frac{t^2}{n^2}\right)^2 \geq 2 \frac{t^3}{3n^2}$$
or equivalently if $t \geq 8/3$. Thus we may assume $t < 8/3$.   Note that $8/3$ lies between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, and $\pi/2$ is an inflection point for cosine.  In the range $\pi/2 \leq t < 8/3$, $\cos(t) \leq 0$ and we may estimate
$$ 1 - \cos(t-\varepsilon) \geq 1 - \varepsilon\geq 1 - \frac{t^3}{3n^2}$$
by \eqref{2}, and so \eqref{3} will be obeyed (just using the second term on the LHS) if
$$ 2 \frac{n}{2} \frac{t^2}{n^2} \left( 1 - \frac{t^3}{3n^2} \right) \geq 2 \frac{t^3}{3n^2}$$
which simplifies to
$$ \frac{2}{3} t + \frac{t^3}{3n^2} \leq n$$
which one can easily verify for $n \geq 3$ and $t \leq 8/3$.

Finally we need to cover the range $0 < t < \pi/2$, which is the most delicate case (as already illustrated by the numerics). The left-hand side of \eqref{3} decays like $t^4$ as $t \to 0$, so, we need to make sure that our bound on the right-hand side does also; the previous $1$-Lipschitz estimate \eqref{5} will no longer suffice. We rewrite \eqref{2} slightly as
$$ (r-1)^2 + 2(r-1) (1 - \cos(t)) \geq 2r (\cos(t-\varepsilon)-\cos(t))$$
and observe from the concavity of cosine in this region that
$$ \cos(t-\varepsilon)-\cos(t) \leq \varepsilon \sin(t),$$
gaining us a crucial additional power of $t$ in the limit $t \to 0$ compared to \eqref{5}.
Since
$$ \frac{1-\cos(t)}{\sin(t)} = \tan\frac{t}{2} \geq \frac{t}{2}$$
it will thus suffice to establish the bound
$$ 2(r-1) \frac{t}{2} \geq 2r \varepsilon.$$
From \eqref{2}, \eqref{4}, it would suffice to show that
$$ 2 \frac{n}{2} \frac{t^2}{n^2} \frac{t}{2} \geq 2 r \frac{t^3}{3n^2}$$
which simplifies to
$$ r \leq \frac{3}{4} n.$$
A key point here is that all the powers of $t$ have canceled out.
Now we can bound
$$ r \leq \left(1 + \frac{(\pi/2)^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2} \leq \exp\left( \frac{(\pi/2)^2}{n^2} \frac{n}{2} \right) = \exp\left( \frac{\pi^2}{8n}\right)$$
and the claim easily follows for $n \geq 3$.

Answer (score 7):

This is to complement the inequality
$$|(1+it)^n-1|\ge b_1(n,t):=|e^{int}-1|,\tag{10}\label{10}$$
proved by [Terry Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/a/455620/36721) for real $t$ and natural $n$, by the following inequality:
$$|(1+it)^n-1|\ge b_2(n,t):=(1+t^2)^{n/2}-1\ge b_3(n,t):=nt^2/2 \tag{20}\label{20}$$
for real $t$ and real $n\ge0$.

For any fixed real $t\ne0$, the lower bound $b_2(n,t)$ on $|(1+it)^n-1|$ grows exponentially in $n$, whereas the lower bound $b_1(n,t)$ remains bounded by $2$. More generally, the lower bound $b_2(n,t)$ (and even the lower bound $b_3(n,t)$) will be better than $b_1(n,t)$ if $nt^2$ is large enough (say if $nt^2>4$).

To prove \eqref{2}, just note that
$$|(1+it)^n-1|^2=1 - 2 c (1 + t^2)^{n/2} + (1 + t^2)^n\ge b_2(n,t)^2,$$
where $c:=\cos(n\arctan t)\le1$.

It is now also seen that, for any real $T\ge\tan\dfrac{2\pi}n$, there is some $t\in(0,T]$ such that the lower bound $b_2(n,t)$ on $|(1+it)^n-1|$ is exact, in the sense that $|(1+it)^n-1|=b_2(n,t)$. Actually, the lower bound $b_2(n,t)$ on $|(1+it)^n-1|$ is exact for all $t=\tan\dfrac{2\pi k}n$, where $k=0,1,\dots$.

---

Here are the graphs for $n=100$

- gold
  $$
  \Big\{\Big(t,\dfrac{|(1+it)^n-1|}{b_1(n,t)}\Big)\colon0<t<0.6,b_1(n,t)\ge b_2(n,t)\Big\}
  $$
  and
- blue
  $$
  \Big\{\Big(t,\dfrac{|(1+it)^n-1|}{b_2(n,t)}\Big)\colon0<t<0.6,b_2(n,t)\ge b_1(n,t)\Big\}
  $$

[image]

Comment: if I may, the lower bound $b_2$ is the lower bound of the OP ($|z^n|-1$, blue curve in his plot).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Thank you for your comment. As discussed in the answer, the lower bound $b_2(n,t)$ may be much greater than $b_1(n,t)$ even for small $t$, provided that $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could set $z = 1+it=re^{i\theta}$ with $r=(1+t^2)^{1/2}$ and $\theta=\arctan t$ so
$$|1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1}| = \frac{|r^ne^{in\theta} - 1|}{|it|} = \frac{(r^{2n}-2r^n\cos(n\theta)+1)^{1/2}}{|t|}.$$
$$|1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1}| = \frac{\sqrt{(1+t^2)^n-2(1+t^2)^{n/2}\cos(n\arctan t)+1}}{|t|}.$$

Comment: The series expansion of the right hand side of the last equation to order 4 is  $$ n+\frac{1}{24} \left(-n^3+6 n^2-5 n\right) t^2+\frac{n \left(n^4-20 n^3+150 n^2-340
   n+209\right) t^4}{1920}+O\left(n^7 t^6\right),$$ which exemplifies the general problem that for fixed $t$ the error term of any series approximation  grows with   $n^{2\,k+1} t^{2\,k}$.A similar problem seems to apply to the nice approximation by @Carlo Beenakker.

Comment: indeed, the inequality is tight for $t\ll 1/n$.